# Encountered a DiscordAPIError while executing command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My bot runs in a command handling system and I am coding a purge slash command where it will delete the number of messages based on the user value.

This is what I wrote for the code:

```
const { ApplicationCommandOptionType, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  permissionsRequired: [PermissionFlagsBits.Administrator],
  name: "purge",
  description: "Delete a specified number of messages",
  options: [
    {
      name: "value",
      description: "The number of messages to delete",
      required: true,
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.Integer,
    },
  ],
  callback: async (client, interaction) => { // Use 'interaction' instead of 'message'

      // Get value from user argument
      const amount = interaction.options.getInteger('value');

      // Check if the argument is a valid number
      if (isNaN(amount) || amount < 1 || amount > 100) {
      return interaction.reply({ content: `Please provide a valid number between 1 and 100.`, ephemeral: true });
      } else {

      // Delete the requested amount of messages
      await interaction.channel.bulkDelete(amount);
      const reply = await interaction.reply(`Deleted ${amount} message(s).`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        try {
          interaction.deleteReply();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the code to work by deleting the number of messages, let's say 5 for example, and then replying to me with:
`Deleted 5 message(s).`

And then after a few tries I encountered a `DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction` error. I realized that the bot did not reply when I used a value of more than 1. It only worked when I purged 1 message.

Any solutions?

Comment: Try deferring your reply at the beginning and then using `interaction.updateReply()` after bulk deleting. --Also, your try/catch block won't be effective unless you `await` the deleteReply promise